# Having trouble to specify a result with factors that are decimals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis

I am reading a book of physics and the first chapter is and introduction to physics and to measurements. It touches on the subject of significant figures but it gives only three or four examples, my head get full of "and ifs". So tried to watch some videos but the "and ifs" still remain.

In the video, the instructor multply 32.48 by 1.2 getting, 38.996. He said that the result is actually 38 because 1.2 has only two significant figures.

I am in doubt in the case of 1334.823 multiplied by 3.2 equals 4271.4336. Limiting the result of 4271.4336 to only two significant figures doesn't make sense (considering that 3.2 has two significant figures).

How to proceed in this case?

Comment: $4300$ is the correct answer, due to the strong uncertainty on $3.2$. This is how that works.

Comment: 32.48  * 1.15 = 37.352 and 32.48  * 1.25 = 40.6 so the answer must be between 37.352 and 40.6

Comment: Seems to me that he should have rounded it to 39

Comment: The overriding principle is that you want to be confident in the value of every digit you write down, possibly with some uncertainty  in the very last digit. In your example, you don't know what comes after 3.2. Was it 3.200000? Or maybe it was rounded down from 3.249999, or rounded up from 3.15? Accounting for the range of possible values of what digits come after 3.2, we could get a value of the final answer that ranges from 4204.7 to 4338.2, with the "average" value being 4271.4. Therefore 4300 represents as much confidence as you should have in the result, with some uncertainty on 3.

Comment: I think that the books don't go further with more complex examples because it is irrelevent to highschool students. In a test the examiner will have empathy. At least I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing and for whom.  If your numbers are measurements, you are concerned about the accuracy of the instruments.  If you are solving problems for a teacher, he (or she) should tell you what they want.  When I started teaching, we were doing calculations with a slide rule.  I told my students to assume that all numbers were accurate, but that they were allowed a small error in the third significant figure of an answer.  With the advent of calculators, I stayed with that rule.  In the lab, all numbers came with a range of possible error.